# What determines the length of `.wav` files?

Tags: python, wav, librosa, music21

I'm currently using `music21` and `midi2audio` to generate `.wav` files for the purpose of machine learning. I have observed a really weird fact.

```
path = '/Users/CatLover/Documents/DataScience/Insight/MusicDetector/music/'
npath = '/Users/CatLover/Documents/DataScience/Insight/MusicDetector/noise/'
nmpath = '/Users/CatLover/Documents/DataScience/Insight/MusicDetector/noisy_music/'
tpath = '/Users/CatLover/Documents/DataScience/Insight/MusicDetector/test_music/'
tnmpath = '/Users/CatLover/Documents/DataScience/Insight/MusicDetector/test_noisy_music/'

def build_dataset(char_list):
    dictionary = dict()
    for char in char_list:
        dictionary[char] = len(dictionary)
    reverse_dictionary = dict(zip(dictionary.values(), dictionary.keys()))
    return dictionary, reverse_dictionary

def repeating_music(char, length):
    preamble = 'tinyNotation: 4/4'
    for i in range(length):
        preamble = preamble + ' ' + char + '4'
    music = music21.converter.parse(preamble)
    music.write('midi', fp = tpath + 'test1' + '.midi')
    subprocess.call(["midi2audio", tpath + 'test1' + '.midi', tpath + 'test1' + '.wav'])
    test_X = segmenting(tpath + 'test1' + '.wav')
    test_y = np.full(length, dic[char])
    return test_X, test_y
char_list = ["r","CCC","CCC#","DDD","DDD#","EEE","FFF","FFF#","GGG","GGG#","AAA","AAA#","BBB","CC","CC#","DD","DD#","EE","FF","FF#","GG","GG#","AA","AA#","BB","C","C#","D","D#","E","F","F#","G","G#","A","A#","B","c","c#","d","d#","e","f","f#","g","g#","a","a#","b","c'","c'#","d'","d'#","e'","f'","f'#","g'","g'#","a'","a'#","b'","c''","c''#","d''","d''#","e''","f''","f''#","g''","g''#","a''","a''#","b''"]
dic, rdic = build_dataset(char_list)
```

Using `librosa.get_duration()` I can see that a `.wav` file with 2 `F` notes only is only about 50% longer than a `.wav` file with only one `F` note. Moreover such ratios are independent of what notes are used unless `r` is used. Why is this true?

Comment: The size of a .wav file is determined by the length of the sound, the number of samples per second, and the size of each sample. You might get different results if the format isn't .wav, for example .mp3.

Comment: The details don't match the question. `get_duration` returns the duration in seconds of the audio, which is (somewhat) independent of the file size.  It is entirely expected that two notes played at a fixed tempo will have twice the duration of a single note.

Answer (score 0):

A 2-note file being 150% of the length of a 1-note file (instead of 200%) is likely a consequence of the single trailing rest added by `music21` by default. There is a [proposed enhancement](https://github.com/cuthbertLab/music21/issues/1141) to provide a keyword to bypass doing that. Quoting from that issue:

> End delay is on by default because a lot of MIDI players otherwise render a sharp pop-end to cutting off sound from a still-playing waveform.